# Android 13 webview change images to obj on the edit click

Tags: android, webview, scale

I have issue.

I'm using webview for html loading. Webview contains contenteditable="true" for editing.

Html can be with img and blockquote tag.

In android till 12 webview all img show fine, but in android 13, then you click in webview for editing, webview change real images to obj as shown in screen:

[image]

It seems like webview applies some resizing or scaling.

Comment: Seeing the same thing. For some reason our webviews work fine on Pixel devices on Android 13. This is only happening on Samsung devices that have Android 13.

Comment: Yes, only on samsung phones with android 13. We checked two samsung s21 ultra, the same versions, the same settings (android/webview etc), but only one phone has such problem.

Comment: This html reproduces the issue for me on Samsung running Android 13:


<div id="editor" contenteditable>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
    <p style="font-size:medium;">r roofing pl<br/></p>
    <p style="font-size:medium;">r roofing pl<br/></p>
</div>


For me, changing "r roofing pl" to some other letter such as "r roofing pi" and the problem goes away. Removing the last paragraph and the problem goes away.

Comment: I tried using different versions of webview with no luck